# FullCalendar is NOT ordering events with eventOrder

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

fullcalendar.io isn't ordering my events correctly:

```
events = {
      
      "color": "purple",
      "date": "2022-08-07",
      "title": "Eicha"
    },
    {
      "color": "green",
      "date": "2022-08-07",
      "title": "Tish'a B'Av"
    }
}
```

This is my component that wraps FullCalendar

```
template>
  <FullCalendar
    :options="calendarOptions" />
</template>

<script>
import '@fullcalendar/core/vdom' // solves problem with Vite
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'


export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar // make the <FullCalendar> tag available
  },
  props: ['readings'],
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick,
        height: '100%',
        events: events,
        eventOrder: 'color'
      }
    }
  }
```

However, the sorted result is incorrect:
[image]

How do I get FullCalendar to properly sort the events according to `eventOrder` ? It doesn't seem to do anything. The green should event should appear BEFORE the purple event

Comment: Did you try using `eventOrder: '-color'` ? Check if the ordering changes.

Comment: I did but it does nothing :( It's just ignoring it completely it seems

Comment: If you could make a simple codepen/codesandbox example of it. It will help to debug.

Answer (score 0):

What version of fullCalendar are you using? Assuming it's the latest v5 then The [eventOrder](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder) documentation says it accepts properties from the Event Object as arguments. But the [event object documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) doesn't list "color" as a property (it's usable when inputting an event - i.e. it's [parseable by fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing), but isn't exposed as a property of a fullCalendar event once it's loaded.

Also even if the above were not the case, I think you're assuming that fullCalendar will do an alphabetic string comparison on the words "purple" and "green". Since it also accepts colour values in other formats (e.g. hex or RGB) I think it is unlikely  it would store them like that internally, so the comparison still wouldn't work as expected.

A simple solution is to also specify the same colour value in a custom property, which fullCalendar can then find the "extendedProps" of the object.

e.g.

```
events: [
      {
      "test": "purple",
      "color": "purple",
      "date": "2022-08-07",
      "title": "Eicha"
    },
    {
      "test": "green",
      "color": "green",
      "date": "2022-08-07",
      "title": "Tish'a B'Av"
    }
]
```

and then

```
eventOrder: "test"
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BarxKzv